# WebTest not appearing in Fiddler save menu

Tags: fiddler, webtest

I am trying to save a fiddler output to a .webtest format.  I used to select file/save as but now I cannot see the .webtest option.  Could anyone tell me why this might have dissappeared from the Fiddler save menu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have version 2.3.0.5 of Fiddler and the .WebTest appears under 
File->Export Sessions->All Sessions/Selected Sessions->Drop down for Visual Studio WebTest